# Reading data from 3 different text file which are in different format

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, endpoint

I want to read data from 3 different text file which has got different format as shown below, based on some input source and destination I need to fetch records from below 3 formats and need to fill my model that will display non redundant records to the client side, I am not sure how can I get filtered non redundant records from these 3 different files. I am trying to achieve it with a web app, by creating an endpoint.

```
http://{localhost}/searchFlights/{Origin}/{Destination}

Provider1 -------------- 
Origin,Departure Time,Destination,Destination Time,Price
 LAS,6/23/2014 13:30:00,LAX,6/23/2014 14:40:00,$151.00 
YYZ,6/15/2014 6:45:00,YYC,6/15/2014 8:54:00,$578.00 
MIA,6/23/2014 19:40:00,ORD,6/23/2014 21:45:00,$532.00 

Provider2 -------------- 
Origin,Departure Time,Destination,Destination Time,Price 
JFK,6-21-2014 17:55:00,YEG,6-21-2014 23:23:00,$589.00 
LAS,6-22-2014 9:45:00,YYZ,6-22-2014 21:20:00,$549.00 

Provider3 -------------- 
Origin|Departure Time|Destination|Destination Time|Price 
LAS|6/29/2014 14:55:00|LAX|6/29/2014 16:10:00|$201.00 
MIA|6/17/2014 14:55:00|ORD|6/17/2014 17:10:00|$542.00
```

I am not sure either I should fill all my list collection with all the records or should fetch filtered records if so I even don't know how to read records?
Please give me some help on the above thing.

Comment: Anything you have tried already?

Comment: Seems there's a seperators which shapes like ', and |'. you can split each line with seperators and use it with columns.

Comment: There is actually no question here, just a statement of intent and some pondering. so we cant help you

Comment: How can I filter records here in flat file, or how should i bind all records to my model where i can fire some linq query to get relevant records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is as follows:

1. Create an object (POCO) which has the properties specified in the files.
2. Override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods so that you can determine how are 2 objects equal. (This will allow you to filter out duplicates).
3. Create a `Factory` which given a path and a file type, will yield an `IEnumerable` with all the objects in the file.
4. Call the factory above and throw all the lists that are returned into a `HashSet`. This should yield a set filled with unique items.

As a note, in Step 3 you can use the `HashSet` as well so that you immediately return a list of unique items, thus potentially saving on the amount of iterations you would need to do on Step 4.

As per your comment, this is where the `Factory` pattern comes in. This class will provide an abstraction as to how are loading objects from the files. Something like so:

```
public class FlightFactory {
    public static final int FILE_TYPE_1;
    public static final int FILE_TYPE_2;
    public static final int FILE_TYPE_3;

    public static IEnumerble<Flight> loadFlightsFromFile(string filePath, int fileType) {
        switch(fileType) {
            case FILE_TYPE_1:
                 return LoadFromFileType1(filePath);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Each `LoadFromFileTypeX` method will then implement an appropriate CSV reader or something similar (and would be declared as private). It's role would be to read and load the stuff from the files.

Comment: OK, I have fair understanding based on your opinion, I just want to know how would I fill my POCO model from 3 different text files?

Comment: @SumitMalviya: I have tried to expand on my answer.

Comment: Should I use factory, I actually need to read data from all three files every time, here in Factory pattern I need to pass file type externally?

Comment: @SumitMalviya: You will either need to do that, or else, make the factory class intelligent enough to identify patterns within the file to know which method it needs ot use.

Comment: @npinit: Why in step 2 I need to implement GetHashCode, GetEqual method woun't be suffice?

Comment: @SumitMalviya: Because in Step 4 you will need to use a hashset, and when you override the `equals` method it is good practice to override the `hashcode` as well.

Comment: @SumitMalviya: Just to be clear, since I just realised that my previous comment might be misleading. The `HashSet` uses the `GetHashCode` method to check if the item is unique or not.

Comment: @– npinti Does HashSet uses the GetHashCode internally or we have to externally call it at the thime of adding the object, as we have to call GetEqual method externally?

Comment: @SumitMalviya: The `GetHashCode` will be used internall.y

Comment: But in Flight Model which overrides GetHashCode and Eual method do not call GetHashCode internally, when I call Equal method in Add function. I am not sure why I have to implement GetHashCode when it is not being used, do I need to write some code externally for hashcode checking too?

Comment: @SumitMalviya: Overriding the `HashCode` should be enough, there is no need for them to call the `base.GetHashCode` or something like that.

Comment: @– npinti: My question is that how the hash code being checked for two objects then, though it is not hitting the break point for gethashcode(), how on adding an obejct checks for hash code being equal of not to and exising object?

Comment: @SumitMalviya: I think it would be better if you check how to work with HashSets